# Rails server not starting due to `require': cannot load such file -- bcrypt_ext (LoadError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I am new to rails and using current rails 5 version with ruby 2.3.0 and i have install device gem for autentication but server is not getting started [Rails guide for devise](http://guides.railsgirls.com/devise)

I have follow all the step and also added gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'
 in my gemfile. since i am using windows 10 the server is not getting started

```
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `require': cannot load such file -- bcrypt_ext (LoadError)
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `block in require'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:259:in `load_dependency'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `require'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bcrypt-3.1.11-x86-mingw32/lib/bcrypt.rb:16:in `rescue in <top (required)>'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bcrypt-3.1.11-x86-mingw32/lib/bcrypt.rb:12:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.14.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:91:in `require'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.14.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:91:in `block (2 levels) in require'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.14.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:86:in `each'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.14.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:86:in `block in require'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.14.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:75:in `each'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.14.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:75:in `require'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.14.3/lib/bundler.rb:107:in `require'
        from C:/Sites/testproject/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:88:in `require'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:88:in `block in server'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:85:in `tap'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:85:in `server'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:49:in `run_command!'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<top (required)>'
        from bin/rails:4:in `require'
        from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

my gem file is below :

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

git_source(:github) do |repo_name|
  repo_name = "#{repo_name}/#{repo_name}" unless repo_name.include?("/")
  "https://github.com/#{repo_name}.git"
end


# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '~> 5.0.1'
# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
#gem 'sqlite3'
gem 'pg'
gem 'devise'

# Use Puma as the app server
gem 'puma', '~> 3.0'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# Use CoffeeScript for .coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.2'
# See https://github.com/rails/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'
# Turbolinks makes navigating your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks', '~> 5'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.5'
# Use Redis adapter to run Action Cable in production
# gem 'redis', '~> 3.0'
# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.11'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug', platform: :mri
end

group :development do
  # Access an IRB console on exception pages or by using <%= console %> anywhere in the code.
  gem 'web-console', '>= 3.3.0'
end

# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]
```

Comment: try to comment `bcrypt` in `gemfile` because `devise` has `bcrypt` in its dependencies, remove `gemfile.lock` and then make new `bundle install`

Comment: where can i find gemfile.lock ? i couldn't find it in gem file

Comment: i found it under my project next to gemfile. I did but still getting same error also i can see file bcrypt_ext.so in generated under "C:\RailsInstaller\Ruby2.3.0\lib\ruby\gems\2.3.0\gems\bcrypt-3.1.11-x86-mingw32\lib\2.2" path how to provide this file to active_support due  to this i cannot install active admin also

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try removing the Gemfile.lock, this file will lock down gems when you `bundle install`

Go to root and in your terminal type `rm -rf Gemfile.lock`, comment `gem bcrypt` and then run again `bundle install`

**UPDATE**

Try `gem uninstall bcrypt` and `gem uninstall bcrypt-ruby`
Then update the bundler `bundle update` and reinstall bcrypt `gem install bcrypt --platform=ruby`

Finally in your Gemfile `gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '3.1.5', :require => 'bcrypt'` and `bundle install`.

Comment: i did but still not working getting same exception after sign up

Comment: Try `gem uninstall bcrypt` and `gem uninstall bcrypt-ruby`, then update the bundler `bundle update,` reinstall it `gem install bcrypt --platform=ruby`, in your Gemfile `gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '3.1.5', :require => 'bcrypt'` and finally `bundle install`.

Comment: yes this works thanks a lot u just made my day mate. can you post this as answer